# ASP.Net MVC: TinyMce Editor is not showing up

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

I am working with tinyMCE editor but editor is not showing in page. I just do not understand the reason why tinyMCE editor is not showing in page.

I followed this link http://rion.io/2014/09/30/integrating-tinymce-into-an-mvc-5-project/ to find how to integrate tinyMCE editor in asp.net mvc project but no luck.

### Here is code snippet:

```
@section scripts{

<script src="~/scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector: '#txtEditor',
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "modern",
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        });
        });

</script>
}
```

when page load then editor does not display but occupy a space and when i inspect html code by firebug then i saw tinymce div is hidden and my textarea is also become hidden.

```
<div id="mceu_13" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" role="application" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="1" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 600px;">
<textarea id="txtEditor" class="form-control" rows="6" name="Description" cols="10" style="width: 30%; display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
</div>
```

I just do not understand the reason why it becomes hidden? If anyone faced the same issue and solved it then please share the knowledge because I want TinyMce Editor to be visible. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: console showing no error.

Comment: `textarea` should be hidden, that's how tinyMCE work. hide initial `textarea `and show it's own `div`. So basically it work i think. Question is why beauty `div` doesn't show up. Have you add css?

Comment: @teovankot which css you are talking about?

Comment: What actually located in `content_css: "css/example.css"`?

Comment: that is commented.......i have not added anything.

Comment: I bet your problem is in css. Check in debug that your init code is executed. If so, check [simple example](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/) on timeMCE site. hope it helps you

Comment: The last comma in the options list is invalid

Comment: @teovankot if css is the issue then tell me where to look and capture the problem. i am using bootstrap v3.3.5 for my web site.

Comment: i remove the extra comma but still no luck :(